# Why doesn't this bash code work?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, subshell

```
x="a=b"
`echo $x`
echo $a
```

I expect the second line to generate "a=b", and execute it in the context of the main shell, resulting in a new variable `a` with value `b`.
However, what I really get (if I enter the commands manually) is the error message after the second line, `bash: a=b: command not found`

Why is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the order in which bash parses the command line.  It looks for variable definitions (e.g. `a=b`) *before* performing variable and command substitution (e.g. commands in backticks).  Because of this, by the time `echo $x` is replaced by `a=b`, it's too late for bash to see this as a variable definition and it's parsed as a command instead.  The same thing would've happened if you'd just used `$x` as the command (instead of echo in backticks).  As in @mvds's answer, the `eval` command can be used to force the command to be reparsed from the beginning, meaning that it'll be recognized as a variable definition:

```
$ x="a=b"
$ `echo $x`
-bash: a=b: command not found
$ $(echo $x)  # Exact same thing, but with cleaner syntax
-bash: a=b: command not found
$ $x  # This also does the same thing, but without some extra steps
-bash: a=b: command not found
$ eval "$x"  # This will actually work
$ echo $a
b
$ a=  # Start over
$ eval "$(echo "$x")"  # Another way of doing the same thing, with extra steps
$ echo $a
b
```

Note that when using `eval` I've put all of the references to `$x` in double-quotes -- this is to prevent the later phases of bash parsing (e.g. word splitting) from happening *twice*, since bash will finish its regular parsing process, then recognize the `eval` command, and then redo the entire parsing process *again*.  It's really easy to get unexpected results from using `eval`, and this removes at least some of the potential for trouble.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
eval $x
```

(And we need 30 characters for this answer to be posted)

Answer (score 3):

What your first echo line does is running in a subshell and returns its value to the callee.. The same result is achieved using `$()` and is - by the way - easier to use than backticks.

So, what you are doing is first running `echo $x` (which returns `a=b`). And, because of the backticks, `a=b` is returned to the shell that tries to run that line as a command which - obviously - won't work.

Try this in a shell:

`$(echo ls)`

And you will clearly see what is happening.

Comment: This helped me with a related issue... I was executing a shell script with backticks and the script did an echo "hi". I didnt capture stdout into a variable in the callee, so the callee tried to execute ./hi and ./hi didnt exist...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `$x` in that funny apostrophes? Without `echo`, echo seems to be only for displaying string, not execute commands.

Comment: They're called backticks (and `$x` and `echo $x` both generate the same result in this case).